# I'm trying to animate a quick sort using matplotlib, but the code only loops correctly without the plot. The code logic is exactly the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, quicksort

Here is the one with the plotting removed, sorts correctly.

```py
def quicksort(arr):


    boundary_stack = [(0, len(arr) - 1)]  # Initialize with full range

    def update(i, arr):



        low_idx, high_idx = boundary_stack.pop()
        low = low_idx
        high = high_idx
        pivot_index = (low + high) // 2
        pivot = arr[pivot_index]


        while low <= high:
            while arr[low] < pivot:
                low += 1
            while arr[high] > pivot:
                high -= 1

            if low <= high:
                arr[low], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[low]
                low += 1
                high -= 1

            print(f"low: {low}, {arr[low]}, high: {high}, {arr[high]} , arr: {arr}")
        # Check if the partitioning is complete based on max and min values
        print(f"low_idx {low_idx} low_val {arr[low_idx]}")
        print(f"high_idx {high_idx} high_val {arr[high_idx]}")
        print(f"pivot {pivot_index} pivot_val {arr[pivot_index]}")
        print(f"subarray{arr[low_idx:high_idx]}")
        if low_idx == pivot_index:
            left_max = arr[low_idx]
        else:
            left_max = max(arr[low_idx:pivot_index])

        if high_idx == pivot_index:
            right_min = arr[high_idx]
        else:
            right_min = min(arr[pivot_index:high_idx])

        if left_max <= pivot <= right_min and (pivot_index - low_idx) > 0 and (
            high_idx - pivot_index) > 0:
            # Partitioning is complete, add boundaries to the stack for further processing
            boundary_stack.append((low_idx, pivot_index - 1))
            boundary_stack.append((pivot_index + 1, high_idx))

        elif low_idx != high_idx and not (left_max <= pivot <= right_min):
            boundary_stack.append((low_idx, high_idx))



        return arr
    while arr != arr.sort():
        update(0,arr)



numbers = [824, 829, 855, 824, 863, 860]

quicksort(numbers)
```

Here is the one that has plotting include and gets stuck"

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def animate_quicksort(arr):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim([0, len(arr)])  # Set x-axis limits
    ax.set_ylim([min(arr), max(arr)])  # Set y-axis limits
    ax.bar(range(len(arr)), arr, width=1)
    ax.set_title('Quick Sort Animation')
    ax.set_xlabel('Index')
    ax.set_ylabel('Value')

    boundary_stack = [(0, len(arr) - 1)]  # Initialize with full range

    def update(i, arr):

        ax.clear()
        ax.set_xlim([0, len(arr)])  # Restore x-axis limits
        ax.set_ylim([min(arr), max(arr)])  # Restore y-axis limits
        ax.bar(range(len(arr)), arr, width=1)
        ax.set_title('Quick Sort Animation')
        ax.set_xlabel('Index')
        ax.set_ylabel('Value')

        low_idx, high_idx = boundary_stack.pop()
        low = low_idx
        high = high_idx
        pivot_index = (low + high) // 2
        pivot = arr[pivot_index]

        # Add a green dotted line for the pivot element
        ax.plot([pivot_index, pivot_index], [min(arr), max(arr)], 'g--', label='Pivot')

        while low <= high:
            while arr[low] < pivot:
                low += 1
            while arr[high] > pivot:
                high -= 1

            if low <= high:
                arr[low], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[low]
                low += 1
                high -= 1

            print(f"low: {low}, {arr[low]}, high: {high}, {arr[high]} , arr: {arr}")
        # Check if the partitioning is complete based on max and min values
        print(f"low_idx {low_idx} low_val {arr[low_idx]}")
        print(f"high_idx {high_idx} high_val {arr[high_idx]}")
        print(f"pivot {pivot_index} pivot_val {arr[pivot_index]}")
        print(f"subarray{arr[low_idx:high_idx]}")
        if low_idx == pivot_index:
            left_max = arr[low_idx]
        else:
            left_max = max(arr[low_idx:pivot_index])

        if high_idx == pivot_index:
            right_min = arr[high_idx]
        else:
            right_min = min(arr[pivot_index:high_idx])

        if left_max <= pivot <= right_min and (pivot_index - low_idx) > 0 and (
            high_idx - pivot_index) > 0:
            # Partitioning is complete, add boundaries to the stack for further processing
            boundary_stack.append((low_idx, pivot_index - 1))
            boundary_stack.append((pivot_index + 1, high_idx))
        elif low_idx != high_idx and not (left_max <= pivot <= right_min):
            boundary_stack.append((low_idx, high_idx))

    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(len(arr)), fargs=(arr,))

    plt.show()


numbers = [824, 829, 855, 824, 863, 860]

animate_quicksort(numbers)
```

I noticed in the test print for the animated one it's missing the element 863

```
low: 3, 855, high: 2, 824 , arr: [824, 829, 824, 855, 863, 860]
low_idx 0 low_val 824
high_idx 5 high_val 860
pivot 2 pivot_val 824
subarray[824, 829, 824, 855, 863]
```

But for the test print in the non-animated code it's correctly identifying 863 as the high value.

```
low: 3, 855, high: 1, 824 , arr: [824, 824, 829, 855, 860, 863]
low_idx 0 low_val 824
high_idx 5 high_val 863
pivot 2 pivot_val 829
subarray[824, 824, 829, 855, 860]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).